# Could not verify key bundle

Tags: installation, cloudera

After complete installation of Cloudera Server when adding hosts to the Server manually it show an error saying:

> Failed to copy installation files /tmp/scm_prepare_node.fQWKTg4D
>   Could not verify the key bundle

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4PfS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Changing "Repository Location" to "Public Cloudera Repository" where you can chose the Repository (STEP 3 in the setup routine) fixed the failure.

But it means, that your nodes in the network are not correctly setup.
your nodes have to be in the correct form in `/etc/hosts` like
192.168.1.3 node2.example.com node2
192.168.1.4 node3.example.com node3

Moreover, check if each node has the correct name with 'hostname -f'. If not change it using `hostnamectl set-hostname`, e.g. with `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname node2`.